# Feedback for data analysis needed

Tags: multiple-regression

I'd appreciate some feedback on the approach to conduct data analysis for my study.

The ultimate goal of the project is to build a predictive model for treatment outcome.
The first study is supposed to be a benchmark and use traditional statistical methods to select group level predictors. Second study will imply building an ML model for individual-level prediction and is to be compared performance-wise with the benchmark study.
**My question concerns the first study.**

There are over 2000 observations and hundreds of potential predictors of different types collected from different sources. The dependent variable is post-treatment symptom level (continuous).

What I'm doing now is running univariate regressions with each potential predictor pre-selecting those established in the literature (and some domain knowledge based) to later include in a multiple regression model.

Please provide feedback on whether it's a reasonable approach and what its drawbacks are. Important caveat is that I'm quite junior and would prefer to abstain from overly complicated methods at this point if the benefit is marginal.

Comment: You might find it helpful to review relevant sections in [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/). Perhaps start with [Case Study in Data Reduction](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/impred.html)?